# CodeIgniter base_url(), link in localhost gives me to live server

Tags: codeigniter, url, hyperlink, base-url

I am working on web page in CodeIgniter in my localhost but this webpage is also in live server.

It uses `base_url()` for all links.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>assets/style.css">
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
...
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>show/edit/other">
```

When I click on link in localhost it gives mi live server address, so I can't do anything in localhost.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Check if `$config['base_url']` in `APPPATH . 'config/config' . EXT` is set well. Edit: Didn't see Phillip's answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two folders inside `application/config` one for production(live server) and one for development(localhost)

- development   => application/config/development
- production    => application/config/production

Then copy any file in the main `application/config` folder and paste it into both `development` and `production` folders.

**application/config/development/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost';
```

**application/config/production/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
```

Based on your ENV constant in `index.php` it will load settings from either production or development folders.  So if ENV == 'development' the settings in `application/config/development` will get used.

If you want a relative path to your assets, add this to the `HEAD` of your html

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>" />
```

Then you can just ref your assets like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css" />
```

Comment: what with file application/config/config.php should i delete it ?

Comment: You can yes, once you have a copy of it in both `development` and `production` folders. You can do the same with `database.php`

Comment: Okey I did what you say but my  link show to non existing link it looks like for example  http://localhost/assets/style.css  .

Comment: You need to set it to the correct url for localhost `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/<namespace>'`  OR you could leave it blank  `$config['base_url'] = ''` If you are working locally, you need to make sure `ENV=='development'` inside `index.php`

Comment: In index.php there is default development: define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');. I also set it to the correct url  $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/<namespace>'  but the result is that only index page of the projekt is loading right.

Comment: links in lives server are good but in localhost only in index page , it loads .css .js ... but when i click to link from index page it throw me to non existing link but url seems good

Comment: Localhost should match where your project folder is. http://localhost/your_project or leave base_url empty and codeigniter will guess it

Comment: I tried this for the  first time, write path or leave base_url empty, the result was the same. Index.php is loading but nothing more. I will find the problem but when ....

Comment: I don't really know what it could be, you say everything works ok on index.php yet all views are run through index.php. My solution should work.

Comment: yes your solution works excellent and it helps me but my problem will be maybe somewhere in controller where url is viewed ... when i try call something with ending .php .jpg .css .... it works fine but when i call something without ending like      <a href=" <?= base_url() ?>show/edit/car"> , there  is problem error 404 . But this problem is only in localhost

Comment: finally, problem was in CI in .htaccess with RewriteBase I set it off

Answer (score 3):

You can set the below code to config.php and it will take relavent url if you are in localhost then it will take localhost and if you are in the live server then it will take live url.

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;

//$config['base_url']   = 'http://localhost/abc/';
```

Comment: the best way to define base url i was facing an issue for a long time only this solution resolved my issues i wish i could give you 100 upvotes..:)

Answer (score 0):

No need to touch config.php. Follow this solution, it will work both in local as well as in live, even after removing index.php through htaccsss

FOR adding files(css,images,js etc) use like following

```
  <?php echo base_url('assets/js/test.js');?>
```

and FOR rest of the stuff use following

```
   <?php echo site_url('controller/metho_name');?>
```

It will handle automatically in live or local server and keep your config.php as it is.

Thanks